# CMD Find first occurrence of string in file then replace sub-string based on the number of occurrences of other sub-string

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, cmd, iteration

I need to use CMD to find the first occurrence of a string in a file, then replace part of that string based on the number of occurrences of a character or sub-string within the originally matching string.

I have files in directories of an unknown depth that need to have all their strings updated based on relative paths.

I'm using a `For /F` to iterate through my generated file list, e.g., `FOR/F "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\path\To\FileList.txt) do [`MyAnswerHere`] %%i`

So let's say the first `%%i` is `C:\Dev\WorkSpace\proto\wip\vcpp\io\SomeTool.vcxproj` and the string I'm looking for is `<Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)CHANGEME\somePath\ThisProjectsProps.props" />`

and the sub-string I'm looking for is `CHANGEME` to the End-of-Line

and what I need to change `CHANGEME` to EOL to is `..\` for each occurrence of `\`, minus 3, as I don't care about the `\` in the path leading up to the workspace root, or the last `\` leading to the file itself, and then finish it by appending `Properties\AllTools.props" />`

So the end result would be updating that file's string to

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\..\..\Properties\AllTools.props" />`

Comment: Use [JREPL.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044): `jrepl <SRC.txt >DEST.txt "(CHANGEME.+?\\)([^\\]+?\x22)" "$1.replace(/.+?\\/g, '..\\') + $2" /i /j` or any other regex-capable cli tool.

Comment: I do not believe that this comment would actually answer my question, only part of it. If I am wrong, please create an answer that points out how it addressed the question's needs, and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Not sure why believing is an issue if you can test it on a copy of the files.

Comment: If you're confident enough to promote your comment to an answer, I will be confidant enough to test it. There are multiple goals in this answer and I do not see how the switches you used when correlated to the link you provided addressed them.

Comment: That has become convoluted. I'm not that interested.

Comment: My question was not edited after you answered. If you do not believe your comment answers this question, then please remove your comment as to not confuse future viewers of this question.

Comment: My comment was an example of using JREPL that I thought you might be able to modify for your needs. Good luck waiting for someone to provide you a 100% complete solution that requires no further adjustment.